# What is the asymptotic behavior of $e^{Bt} v$ for $B$ a matrix satisfying Perron-Frobenius and $v$ a positive vector?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, asymptotics

Let $B$ be a nonnegative, irreducible, and primitive matrix.

Let $\lambda$ be the spectral radius of $B$ and $u$ an eigenvector of $B$ with positive entries associated with $\lambda$ (by Perron-Frobenius).

Let $v$ be a vector with positive entries.

Is it true that there exists a positive constant $\alpha$, such that $e^{Bt} v \sim \alpha e^{\lambda t} u$ when $t \to +\infty$? Why?

Comment: The answer is yes. One approach is to consider the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of the matrix 
$$
e^{- \lambda t} e^{Bt} = e^{(B - \lambda I)t}.
$$

Comment: Can you detail? In particular, why is it impossible that $\alpha = 0$

Comment: Actually I hadn't thought of that possibility. That said, we can rule it out by noting that $\alpha = 0$ can only occur if $v \in \operatorname{im}(B - \lambda I)$, which is the subspace orthogonal to the left eigenspace of $B$ associated with $\lambda$.

Comment: I'll put a complete answer when I get the chance, if someone doesn't beat me to it. By the way, a "left" eigenvector of $B$ is an eigenvector of $B^T$ (in the usual sense)

Comment: Ok got it. Just wrote an answer. The key idea is indeed to work with $B'$ the transpose of $B$ that satisfies as well Perron-Frobenius.

Comment: Thx Ben Grossmann

Comment: I believe primitive plays no role.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is true. By the Perron Frobenius theorem, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $B$ with algebraic mutliplicity $1$.

First, showing that $\alpha \ne 0$: let $w$ denote the positive eigenvector of $B^T$ associated with $\lambda$. I claim that if $v$ can be written as a linear combination of generalized eigenvectors of $B$ associated with eigenvalues not equal to $\lambda$, the we must have $w^Tv = 0$. Indeed, we can write the characteristic polynomial of $B$ in the form $p(x) = (x-1) q(x)$, with $q(1) \neq 0$. We note that $q(B)v = 0$, so that
$$
w^Tv = \frac 1{q(1)}(q(B^T)w)^T v = \frac 1{q(1)}w^Tq(B) v = \frac 1{q(1)}w^T0 = 0.
$$
However $v,w$ are both positive vectors, which means that $w^Tv \neq 0$.

Now, note that we can write $v = \alpha u + \beta x$, where $\alpha > 0$ and $x$ is a linear combination of generalized eigenvectors of $B$ associated with eigenvalues whose real part is strictly smaller than $\lambda$. The rest is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

We can indeed write $v = \alpha u + y$ where $y \in \text{Im}(B- \lambda I) = \text{Ker}(B' - \lambda I)^\perp$.

So $v- \alpha u$ is orthogonal to $\text{Ker}(B' - \lambda I)$.

But from Perron-Frobenius applied to $B'$, the latter space is a line directed by a vector with positive entries. We deduce that $\alpha>0$.

The result follows easily.